# How to write a good long sentence with different phrases

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

I would like to write a sentence which includes some reasons. In my study, I extend a method to a new one. I would like to say that I extend the first one which does something to a new one which overcomes the limitation of the first method. Here is my try:

*This method extends the existing method of A, which only allow modeling bivariate dependency, to method B, which allow modeling different dependency at a time.*

Is this correct? Is there a better way to express my sentence instead of repeating *which*?

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maryam. It is not clear to me how method B differs from method A. Depending on what that really is, this may be suitable for your needs:

*Method B extends the existing method A, from allowing the modeling of only one bivariate dependency to allowing the modeling of different bivariate dependencies.*

An even briefer form could then be:

*Method B extends the existing method A, from allowing the modeling of only one to different bivariate dependencies.*

Comment: Requests for clarification should be comments, not answers.

Comment: @Andrew I shall refrain from responding on the grounds I prefer to maintain a civil oine. If this "rule" was applied equally, I would try to comply. As it is not, I choose to do what I consider most constructive for the questioner's needs.

Comment: Do what you like, but don't be too surprised by the downvotes.   You should also be aware that questions that constitute "proofreading" are routinely closed.  If there is any way to edit your question to address some overarching grammar rule, rather than correcting this one example, then I might reverse my vote.

Comment: Okay, @Andrew. I will take note of what you say the problem is. If that results in some changes in the answers/comments I make, it will be because I assess that serves the needs of the questioners better, not because of potential downvotes. But please, continue doing what you see as being best for the site. I have no intentions of arguing. :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that answers are intended to be part of a "library" with information relevant to many people, not just the person asking. In the [help] under How do I ask a good question? it explicitly states "Make it relevant to others". Requests for clarification *should* be comments, because it is expected that the author will update their question. Then the comment can be flagged as "no longer needed". Correcting or rewording specific sentences doesn't really help other learners, so good alternative to posting questions like that as a Q&A is to discuss it in [chat].